# JSON error: <error: expected ']' error: 1 errors parsing expression >

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm having trouble parsing my JSON. The JSON is:

```
{"privatecode":"XDhUZQ1rA2gBZwshV2NrZQRnDmVPZQhuVj7WOlNrC29SPwg6VDUGelU1DahQNlc1AWpcPVBuWmc"}
```

I'm using following code:

```
id parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&localError];
```

The class of `parsedObject` is `NSDictionary`, but it contains the following error:

```
(<invalid>) [0] = <error: expected ']'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
>
```

Of course I could say:

```
NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&localError];
```

but this makes no difference. I just want to get the `privatecode` as an `NSString` object, so what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: Some more code I'm using:

```
NSLog(@"Response: %@", [request responseString]);
id parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[request responseData] options:0 error:&localError];
```

`request` is of type `ASIHTTPRequest`. The output of the log is:

```
Response: {"privatecode":"XDhUZQ1rA2gBZwshV2NrZQRnDmVPZQhuVj7WOlNrC29SPwg6VDUGelU1DahQNlc1AWpcPVBuWmc"}
```

Comment: I tried your json and the code, it works. I think you are using some other JSON, not the provided one.

Comment: The debugger variables view has problems sometimes. Better NSLog the dict in your code or use `po` in the debugger console.

Comment: @MartinR You are SO right! It parses without problems, still giving an error in debug mode. Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get now?

Comment: No error anymore, the debugger is showing the same error, though it's working fine. Not sure why, but it works fine. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&localError];
```

I am using this for my project without any problem. Hope this helps. :)

**EDIT:**

From your error it seems that it is an array (array starts with '['). But your posted JSON is Dictionary (starts with '{'). It is weird. I searched and got this. Check this:

```
if ([returnedFromWeb respondsToSelector:@selector(objectAtIndex:)]) { // you can replace respondsToSelector:@selector(objectAtIndex:) by isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]
  //it's an array do array things.
} else {
  //it's a dictionary do dictionary things.
}
```

Comment: That make no sense, did you check the value of kNilOptions ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I was getting the same error you are but my response is an array. Since it looks like you are expecting a dictionary I'll include what that might look like.

```
    id test = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:error];
    NSArray *array;
    NSDictionary *dictionary;
    if ([test isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) { 
        //it's an array do array things.
        array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:test];
    } else {
        //it's a dictionary do dictionary things.
        dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:test];
    }
```

At this point you should be able to access the contents of the array or dictionary.

Simplified:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:error]];
```

OR

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:error]];
```